# How SQL Server place the data to disk

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hey, does anyone know a good site that shows how SQL Server place the data to disk?

Comment: Your question is not specific enough...It uses transaction logs and data files, like most databases engine

Comment: So, what I want to read and check the "physical" is how the data in the tables will be placed physically on the disk. With and without index -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my blog in the [Inside The Storage Engine](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/Inside-the-Storage-Engine.aspx) series and the [On Disk Structures](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/On-Disk-Structures.aspx) series. I wrote a bunch of the SQL Server code that deals with data storage on disk. Start down at the bottom of the series where I go from records up.

Answer (score 0):

[This MS Press book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/073562271X) does a good job of explaining this.

Comment: not exactly. Kalen Delaney's book is much better at internals then the ms press 70-431 book

Comment: It's a start, especially considering how vague the question was.

Answer (score 0):

SQL BOL is probably your best bet for this.  Check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280361.aspx and do some reading up on Pages & Extents, Files and Filegroups, and Transaction Logs... the rest would also be useful, but the database engine architecture is what you really should check into.

You may want to start out with this one though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179355.aspx which is probably the info you are looking for.